# SIM Card Authentication

Tags: smartcard, sim-card, javacard

I'm new to SIM Cards and I'm trying to authenticate to a SIM Card using Gemalto JCardManager (part of Gemalto Developer Suite), with Gemplus USB SmartCard Reader.

Aparently, i have all the necessary keys (kic, kid and kik), but i can't authenticate.

In fact, i have two SIM's: one SIM Card R5 and one USIM Card R5.

I have configured the keys files for both of them, but when i try to authenticate to the SIM Card R5, the following message appears:

```
[ERROR  ] <-   6D 00
Command Exception on command: Authenticate. Authentication failed : INITIALIZE UPDATE : unknown response : VOP sw=6D00
```

And when i try to authenticate to the USIM Card R5, the following message appears:

```
[ERROR  ] <-   6D 00
[ERROR  ] <-   Invalid instruction.
```

Does anyone know what this messages means?

Answer (score 2):

Not all cards supports mutual authentication. Most probably yours doesn't support it.
Is your card gemalto one? If yes, do you have ADM keys of the card?
Actually gemalto has 3 types of cards:

1. Fully native cards without GP at all.
2. Middle range cards, these cards support partially GP but no mutual authentication. On these cards verification of ADM key is enough.
3. High-end cards, these cards support all latest technos.

To verify ADM key you have to send:

```
00 20 00 <adm key number> 08 <adm key value>
```

If you know which keyset hold ADM key, you can send proprietary Verify key command:

```
F0 2A 00 <keyset number> 08 <adm key value>
```

Comment: Hi Nodir, thanks for your help.
Yes, my card is a Gemalto one, but I don’t actually know wich type it is. I can tell that it is a USIM Card.
Is there a easy way to know that?
I don´t have the ADM keys yet, but I already have the KIc, KID and KIK.
What exactly do you mean when you say “To verify ADM key”?
I´m starting now to learn about sim cards. So, i´m sorry about this basic questions.
Antônio

Comment: @user2483059 Please don't ask additional questions within the same question. Try creating another question if you cannot figure it out yourself. Try the documentation for the Gemalto cards - if you cannot figure it out try contacting Gemalto.

Comment: 00 20 00 <adm key number> 08 <adm key value> resulted in error 6400 (No information given)
F0 2A 00 <keyset number> 08 <adm key value> gave me 6e00 (Class not supported)

Answer (score 0):

The message is an ISO 7816-4 specified status word in hexadecimals. It means "INS not supported". This is an indication that that specific authentication command is not supported. This could be because the card is not according to the specifications (you are expecting it to have) or because it is in the wrong life-cycle state.